# Бесконечная загрузка callback (inline) кнопок в vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

При нажатии на кнопку идёт бесконечная загрузка и не появляется `show_snackbar` сообщение.
Пробовал на пк и телефоне.

[image: бесконечная загрузка]

kb.py

```
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor

inln = VkKeyboard(one_time=False, inline=True)

inln.add_callback_button(label='Покажи pop-up сообщение',
                               color=VkKeyboardColor.SECONDARY,
                               payload={"type": "show_snackbar", "text": "привет"})
```

main.py

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkEventType, VkLongPoll

def send(pk, text = None, keyboard = None, sticker_id = None):
    vk.method('messages.send',
             {'user_id': pk[0],
             'message': text,
             'keyboard': keyboard,
             'random_id': 0,
             'sticker_id': sticker_id}) 

def main():
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.from_user:
            msg = event.text.lower()
            id = event.user_id
            domain = vk.method('users.get',
                              {'user_ids': id,
                               'fields': 'domain'})[0]["domain"]
            pk = [id, domain, msg] 
            if msg == "inline":
                send(pk, "тест", kb.inln.get_keyboard())
```

> Long Poll API - 5.131 | Python - 3.9.2

> Как я понял, не я один столкнулся с такой проблемой. В поисках решения нашёл много людей с таким
> же казусом, но разным кодом

Comment: А где ты обрабатываешь различные события?

Comment: Чтобы сформироват запрос используй чето типа Этого:r = vk.messages.sendMessageEventAnswer(
                      event_id=event.object.event_id,
                      user_id=event.object.user_id,
                      peer_id=event.object.peer_id,                                                   
                      event_data=json.dumps(event.object.payload))

Comment: Обновил код @SovaNight